# Combine SWF Flashvars into one file

Tags: flash, flashvars

I have a SWF flash file that uses flashvars.

I am using this code in the SWF:

```
myData = new LoadVars();
myData.onLoad = function ()
{
myText_txt.text = this.content;
};
myData.load("variabletext.txt");
stop ();
```

It loads variables from a text file. The text file contains:

```
content=Title goes here
```

When you view the flash file, you see what the variable "content" is equal to. This requires two files, the SWF file and the text file.

I am looking for a way to combine / convert these two files into one SWF file. Ideally done via the command line. How can I do this?